# Choosing between network optimisation and CPU usage in clientside web development

Tags: performance, optimization, css, web

I'm working on a CSS library that includes hundreds of selectors and rules for quick templating instead of writing regular CSS.
*This is used as a replacement of `attr()` CSS function until it works for any rule and not just `content:`.*

At first I generated a minified CSS file to load. But as there are many loops for each possible values, I've been trying to generate those CSS rules directly in the browser instead.

Here is a sample of a performance result:

- *Prebuilt CSS file :* 150KB / 15ms script CPU usage
- *JS file (injecting in `<style>` element) :* 20KB / 150ms script CPU usage

Of course those results can vary a lot depending on the network and the device. But in overall, what would be the best choice between network optimisation and CPU optimisation *(for any kind of device)*?

Answer (score 1):

There cannot be an universal performance tradeoff. A web app targeted at content creators who work from a beefy gaming PC with a gigabit internet connection will settle on a very different tradeoff than a page targeted at people from developing countries who are using an outdated smartphone over a shaky mobile data connection where bandwidths are measured in the low kbps.

What is striking though is that you are focused on generating a *massive* CSS file. The question is not whether this CSS should be generated locally or pre-built, but whether this CSS approach is really the most appropriate. When your issue is the limited `attr()` support, trying to brute-force your way around this limitation is questionable. Likely, techniques such as using custom properties (variables), style attributes on individual elements, or a bit of JavaScript will be faster and better supported on any metric. While I really cannot recommend them in the general case, frameworks like React and Vue are a nice example of using JavaScript to manage the data flow from your element's attributes into its CSS styles.

Comment: The generated CSS file actually weights less than the minified Bootstrap CSS. The goal is not to add dynamic change on styles (using frameworks) but to get rid of very long css files per page/application and focus on HTML only (just like Bootstrap) - this method is way faster, easier and in the end lighter to make webpage than using regular css files.

Comment: @Tot Sure, it's fine to disagree with my preferences. Stack Overflow does too, and ships a 350KB stylesheet even on the old mobile view. If your method is “faster, easier and in the end lighter” that is great! Just make sure to be clear with yourself about what your requirements and priorities are.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. :) This step is more a fine optimisation, as most modern webapps/websites are indeed heavier in general. But I'm still wondering, in general, what's the best between lighter file weight or lighter CPU usage.

Comment: @Tot Amon's first paragraph explains why your question 'in general' has no answer. By asking for a general answer you remove the possibility of a valid answer.

Comment: @joshp Yes, I see what you mean. Thanks for the advice !